# C++ Eclipse Galileo getting it to display line numbers - how?

Tags: c++, eclipse, line-numbers

### **EDIT: *jldupont*'s suggestion** (*see below*) did the trick

> **Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Show line numbers**

---

I just installed Eclipse Galileo (first time) and am programing in C++ and couldn't get the editor to display the line numbers... When i Googled it I got these directions:

> Go to **Window -> Preferences -> Editor -> Appearance** and check **Show line numbers**

But when I follow those directions - there is no **"Show Line Numbers"** check box? 
where can i get this 'plug-in' of enable this feature? or does Eclipse have line numbers?

note: i have CDT installed

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Show line numbers

Answer (score 10):

I have "Show Line Numbers" in the context menu when I right-click on the left-hand side of the editor pane.